# AutoCompleteTextView - how to disable dropdown when we have one exact match after filtering?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there an easy way to do so?
Because dropdown with one element which is identical to typed text looks redundant.

My adapter is simple, here is the code

```
AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextViewAddress;
...
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AvatarMainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, emailsSet.toEmailStringSet());
    autoCompleteTextViewAddress.setAdapter(adapter);
```

`emailsSet.toEmailStringSet()` returns set of Strings.

When I fill `autoCompleteTextViewAddress` with email identical to one in string set, I can still view a dropdown with one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugly solution, but it works:

```
public class CustomAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {

    public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context,attrs);
    }
    public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context,attrs,defStyle);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean enoughToFilter()
    {
        boolean isEnough=(getThreshold()<=this.getText().length());

        if(isEnough)
        {
            if(this.getAdapter()!=null)
            {
                int itemsCount=0;
                int matchIndex=0;
                String txt = this.getText().toString();
                for (int i=0; i< this.getAdapter().getCount();i++) 
                {
                    String dat = (String)this.getAdapter().getItem(i);
                    if(dat.startsWith(txt))
                    {
                        itemsCount++;
                        matchIndex=i;
                    }
                }
                if(itemsCount == 1)
                {
                     if(((String)getAdapter().getItem(matchIndex)).equals(txt))
                     {
                         isEnough=false;
                     }

                }
            }
        }
        return isEnough;

    }


}
```

Use custom class instead of original `AutoCompleteTextView`.

Overrided `enoughToFilter` function hides dropdown when we have exactly one matching record in our adapter

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the type of code

But here is a SQL example of grabbing the suggestions

```
     If( (select count(*) from /* your code here */) > 1)
     Select /* field */ from /* your code again here */
```

That way it would only show when it has 2 or more suggestions.

Comment: Well maybe. It would help a lot to see a stripped down version of your current code.

Comment: added. there is no sql there it's  simplier